# PHP DOMDocument get image tag and value with getElementsByTagName

Tags: php

I want to get image and any text between `td` tag and I'm using `DOMDocument` class.
Below code could not get and parse image tag with any text between `td`.
For example :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML("<th>Country:</th><td>UAS <img src='www.site.com/image.png' /></td>");
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

It return only `UAS` without `img` tag.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran  i want to have `UAS <img src='www.site.com/image.png' />` to seve into database

Comment: Is regex allowed in your case ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran if with DOMDocument can not pare that i must be use regex. no problem thanks

Comment: @PeeHaa, Why such hatred ? :) Just tell me and I will delete it , you don't have to post it on chat and make this a big issue :)

Comment: @PeeHaa your link is not my answer. with `DOMDocument` we can not get `img` tag between `td` and @ShankarDamodaran tel me to use `regex`

Comment: What makes you say that you cannot get the `img` tag with domdoc when the duplicate question and answer tell you otherwise?

Comment: @TuxWorld, I didn't say you cannot do that with DOM , I asked if `regex` is allowed on your case.